# Add code on anchor click before doing anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I am developing and application with fullPage plugin and I have the following issue:
I want to skip one section if the user is scrolling down, but not skip it if the user has clicked the anchor link pointing to this section.

fullPage plugin provides an event for detecting when the user is scrolling into that div, but this event also fires when the user clicks the anchor instead of scrolling. So I thought I could create a global variable to store if the user has already clicked the anchor or not, so I can detect if skip it or not.(if he has clicked it at least once, it is okey to not skip this section on scrolling)

So the question is, how can I ensure to modify this global variable when the user clicks the anchor, but **before** the plugin event gets fired?(it gets fired when the user clicks the anchor too)

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: 
I made a simple on click event function this way:

```
var shouldSkip = true;
  $('#portfolio-id a').click(function(){
    shouldSkip = false;
});
```

And it seems to be working, but **I need to be sure it will ALWAYS get fired before** the other function that fires with this event.

Just for adding more information, I add the plugin initialization with this funciton I am mentioning.

```
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    paddingTop: '70px',
    paddingBottom: '50px',
    scrollOverflow: true,
    anchors:['home', 'estudio', 'portfolio', 'show-portfolio', 'servicios'],
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
      var leavingSection = $(this);
      console.log(leavingSection);

      if(index == 3 && direction =='down' && shouldSkip){
        alert("Should skip going down");
      }

      else if(index == 5 && direction == 'up' && shouldSkip){
        alert("Should skip going top");
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: use preventDefault() and then update global variable then use window.location

Comment: @Farhan I want all the scrollings to be done by this plugin, because it gives a nice smooth effect and I want every scrolling to have the exact same effect. Therefor I would choose not to use `preventDefault()` and `window.location`. Is there any funciton similar to `preventDefault(),` but more like `beforeDefault()` ??

Comment: Also, I am not sure if `preventDefault()` prevents the plugin from running its code for scrolling to the section, because it is not the default action, it is the plugin's action (The default action on an anchor link is instantly going to the section). Please correct me if I'm wrong, thank you very much for clarifying.

Comment: if you don't want to redirect onclick on anchor then preventDefault will not effect your other stuff attached with anchor. just update your global variable. in your custom click event. leave rest on plugin.

Comment: @Farhan You mean, as I wrote on the edit on my post? This way, how can I be sure my custom click event will be fired before the plugin event does? Again, thank you